# JavaScript ReqEx split by closing bracket and keep the delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am finding difficulty in splitting an string in JavaScript(jquery) by a closing bracket and have to keep the delimiter that is used to split.

```
 ex: (GROUP=test1)(GROUP=test2)(GROUP=test3)(GROUP=test4)
```

needs to be split by using ) and keep the delimiter with it

o/p:

```
(GROUP=test1)
(GROUP=test2)
(GROUP=test3)
(GROUP=test4)
```

i thought of a workaround of replacing ')' with '),' and then split by ',' which will solve my issue..but wanted to do in a clean way..

any help is  greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

```
var source = '(GROUP=test1)(GROUP=test2)(GROUP=test3)(GROUP=test4)';
var results = source.match(/\([^)]*?\)/g);
```

gives the requisite array in `results`.

The regex translates to: `(`, followed by the shortest possible series of characters not including `)`, followed by `)`; return multiple matches

Reference:

- [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)